# Is it possible to change the style of an Android L TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, android-timepicker, android-5.0-lollipop

I was testing my app on an Android L emulator, and I noticed that the TimePickerDialog has significantly changed to this:

[image: Android L TimePickerDialog]

This doesn't fit with the theme of my app, and I wanted to know if it is possible to get the old TimePickerDialog style when running on Android L.

Comment: have you tried using the constructor with theme parameter? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#TimePickerDialog(android.content.Context, int, android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, int, int, boolean)

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Now I can use a TimePicker that doesn't look like it was designed by a child clown.

Comment: I'll add an answer so you can mark the question as answered

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [TimePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#TimePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) constructor with `theme` parameter to specify the theme.

```
TimePickerDialog(Context context, 
                 int theme, 
                 TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callBack, 
                 int hourOfDay, 
                 int minute, 
                 boolean is24HourView)
```

Comment: Is there a default theme that would give back the old version?

Comment: @Zharf For HOLO look and feel you can use `TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK` or`TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT` as `theme` parametar

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change the widget back to the style you see in ICS through Kitkat :(

Comment: @LordRaydenMK these theme IDs are now deprecated

Comment: @VadimKotov well, things changed in 5 years.

Answer (score 43):

Add **android:timePickerMode="spinner"** to the XML

```
    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner">
    </TimePicker>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#timePickerMode

You can choose between **spinner** or **clock** modes. This attribute is only available from API level 21, before that the **spinner** mode was the only option available.

Comment: There is no timePickerMode as far as I am aware. You can only do this for a datepicker (where it is called 'android:datePickerMode').

Comment: There is actually a timePicker ,

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html)

, The code about is from a working example .

Comment: I didn't say there is no TimePicker. I said that I believe there is no android:timePickerMode (and the link you provide indeed makes no mention of this)

Comment: Sorry for the previous link , but am pretty sure there is a timePickerMode, its available from API Level 21 and here is the correct link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#timePickerMode

Comment: Nice one - that feature is well hidden. Note that using the style you also have the classic option (with the buttons) available and not just clock or spinner.

Comment: @Lieuwe Pretty sure there is a timePickerMode. Please verify before you make your statement as this answer is actual the one that works.

Answer (score 16):

If you want the AM / PM to be a picker instead of a button then I recommend you use the single parameter constructor with a `ContextThemeWrapper`:

```
new TimePicker(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar));
```

[image: AM-PM picker]

If you pass the theme into the multiple parameter constructor then you'll end up with a rather ugly AM / PM button, and the colon will be missing between the hour and minute columns.

```
new TimePicker(getActivity(), null, TimePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
```

[image: AM-PM button]

Answer (score 11):

As LordRaydenMK said, use the `TimePickerDialog` constructor with `theme` parameter and provide this theme: `android.R.style.CustomDatePickerDialog`

And in your `Styles.xml` define this:

```
  <style name="CustomDatePickerDialog"
         parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDialogTheme"
         parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:timePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyDatePicker"
         parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: It works. Note, it doesn't work if just set android:timePickerMode inside theme

Answer (score -3):

You can use **android:timePickerMode** attribute in the XML.

For more info: [Read Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker#attr_android:timePickerMode)

Comment: This is pretty much a link-only and duplicated answer.