# Android API 21 - TimePicker widget

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-timepicker

I've got a problem with the `TimePicker` widget on API 21. Until API 19 the `TimePicker` was an up-/down-list like iOS, but in 21+ it's round, like the one in the calendar app.

How can I use the old one in 21+, because it breaks my design, if it is the new widget.

Comment: I recommend this stackoverflow link for a programatically and XML answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449723/is-it-possible-to-change-the-style-of-an-android-l-timepickerdialog

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can specify the spinner-style time picker by setting the timePickerMode attribute to "spinner". The default value on Material is "clock".

```
<TimePicker
    ...
    android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Comment: You can pass a defStyleAttr or defStyleRes in when you create your time picker.

Comment: Is it possible to use this new API 21 timepicker on pre-Lollipop?

Comment: No, it's part of the framework. It may show up in appcompat at some point in the future, though.

Comment: Is there any way for an end user to disable the new time picker? Some users find it really cumbersome to work with.

Comment: No, but as a developer you can use whichever style you like, and you could expose this to the user as a preference (but I would recommend against it).

Comment: How come that attribute is not listed in the docs, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html, here? How did you know where that attribute comes from?

Comment: It needs to be in the class documentation (and it will in the next release) but it's also documented in `android.R.styleable` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TimePicker_timePickerMode). I know it's there because I wrote it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can Programatically use the spinner mode using the custom class. For earlier versions From lolipop it will change the timepicker mode from clock to spinner and it's also allow you to set disable selection of time after a particular time (using setmax() & setmin()). In the below code i used set max() to limit the maximum time.

```
public class RangeTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private int minHour = -1;
    private int minMinute = -1;

    private int maxHour = 25;
    private int maxMinute = 25;

    private int currentHour = 0;
    private int currentMinute = 0;

    private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private DateFormat dateFormat;


    public RangeTimePickerDialog(Context context, int dialogTheme, OnTimeSetListener callBack, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
        currentHour = hourOfDay;
        currentMinute = minute;
        dateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        fixSpinner(context, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);

        try {
            Class<?> superclass = getClass().getSuperclass();
            Field mTimePickerField = superclass.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
            mTimePickerField.setAccessible(true);
            TimePicker mTimePicker = (TimePicker) mTimePickerField.get(this);
            mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
    }

    public void setMin(int hour, int minute) {
        minHour = hour;
        minMinute = minute;
    }

    public void setMax(int hour, int minute) {
        maxHour = hour;
        maxMinute = minute;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        boolean validTime = true;
        if (hourOfDay < minHour || (hourOfDay == minHour && minute < minMinute)){
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (hourOfDay  > maxHour || (hourOfDay == maxHour && minute > maxMinute)){
            validTime = false;
        }

        if (validTime) {
            currentHour = hourOfDay;
            currentMinute = minute;
        }

        updateTime(currentHour, currentMinute);
        updateDialogTitle(view, currentHour, currentMinute);
    }

    private void updateDialogTitle(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        String title = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        setTitle(title);
    }


    private void fixSpinner(Context context, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { // android:timePickerMode spinner and clock began in Lollipop
            try {
                // Get the theme's android:timePickerMode
                //two modes are available clock mode and spinner mode ... selecting spinner mode for latest versions
                final int MODE_SPINNER = 2;
                Class<?> styleableClass = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$styleable");
                Field timePickerStyleableField = styleableClass.getField("TimePicker");
                int[] timePickerStyleable = (int[]) timePickerStyleableField.get(null);
                final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null, timePickerStyleable, android.R.attr.timePickerStyle, 0);
                Field timePickerModeStyleableField = styleableClass.getField("TimePicker_timePickerMode");
                int timePickerModeStyleable = timePickerModeStyleableField.getInt(null);
                final int mode = a.getInt(timePickerModeStyleable, MODE_SPINNER);
                a.recycle();
                if (mode == MODE_SPINNER) {
                    TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) findField(TimePickerDialog.class, TimePicker.class, "mTimePicker").get(this);
                    Class<?> delegateClass = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePicker$TimePickerDelegate");
                    Field delegateField = findField(TimePicker.class, delegateClass, "mDelegate");
                    Object delegate = delegateField.get(timePicker);
                    Class<?> spinnerDelegateClass;
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT != Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        spinnerDelegateClass = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerSpinnerDelegate");
                    } else {

                        spinnerDelegateClass = Class.forName("android.widget.TimePickerClockDelegate");
                    }
                    if (delegate.getClass() != spinnerDelegateClass) {
                        delegateField.set(timePicker, null); // throw out the TimePickerClockDelegate!
                        timePicker.removeAllViews(); // remove the TimePickerClockDelegate views
                        Constructor spinnerDelegateConstructor = spinnerDelegateClass.getConstructor(TimePicker.class, Context.class, AttributeSet.class, int.class, int.class);
                        spinnerDelegateConstructor.setAccessible(true);
                        // Instantiate a TimePickerSpinnerDelegate
                        delegate = spinnerDelegateConstructor.newInstance(timePicker, context, null, android.R.attr.timePickerStyle, 0);
                        delegateField.set(timePicker, delegate); // set the TimePicker.mDelegate to the spinner delegate
                        // Set up the TimePicker again, with the TimePickerSpinnerDelegate
                        timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
                        timePicker.setCurrentHour(hourOfDay);
                        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
                        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
    private static Field findField(Class objectClass, Class fieldClass, String expectedName) {
        try {
            Field field = objectClass.getDeclaredField(expectedName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {} // ignore
        // search for it if it wasn't found under the expected ivar name
        for (Field searchField : objectClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (searchField.getType() == fieldClass) {
                searchField.setAccessible(true);
                return searchField;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using reflection is not future save. I wouldn't use that.