# Android - How to programmatically change timepicker mode?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I had a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926727/android-api-21-timepicker-widget) but using the APIs timepickerdialog (code below) I would like to set timePickerMode property in my class .java is it possible?

```
    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Comment: @DerGolem the timePickerMode, (it can be _clock_ or _spinner_)

Comment: Not currently possible at run time, would you mind filing a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list/?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue. Then I read TimePicker source code. I think we can't change timepicker mode in .java file. Google set mode of TimePicker in contructor method: http://prntscr.com/blkkkd

Comment: Hi, if this is the case, you could after calling the super constructor, to change the mDelgate object using reflection.