# how does the ReadableMap interface in React-native convert JS to JAVA?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I'm trying to understand how to properly pass options from the js side of react-native to the java side.

The react-native bridge uses [ReadableMap](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/ReadableMap.java) to convert but as a Java noob I'm failing to understand how this works.

More specifically I don't understand:

- how the actual conversion works?
- how to tell what type/format the downstream Java code wants?
- how to properly use ReadableMap to do this?

Generally I would like to know how this works but I'll give the specific example I'm looking at to give some context.

---

A react-native package exposes a datetime picker.

The JS side has a showTimePicker method:

```
showTimePicker(date, callback) {
    date = date || new Date();
    console.log(this.props);
    debugger
    var options = {
        ...this.props,
        hour:date.getHours(),
        minute:date.getMinutes()
    };
    RCTDateTimePicker.showTimePicker(options, function (hour, minute) {
        date.setHours(hour);
        date.setMinutes(minute);
        callback(date);
    });
}
```

`RCTDateTimePicker.showTimePicker` is bridged to a Java [method](https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-datetime/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/keyee/datetime/TimePicker.java#L22) on the native side:

```
@ReactMethod
public void showTimePicker(ReadableMap options, Callback callback) {
    DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePicker(options, callback);
    timePicker.show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

which calls

```
public TimePicker(ReadableMap options, Callback callback) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.callback = callback;
    hour = options.hasKey("hour") ? options.getInt("hour") : c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = options.hasKey("minute") ? options.getInt("minute") : c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}
```

which creates and instance of an Android [TimePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html). My goal is to change the style of the Timepicker from watch to spinner.

There is a settable XML attribute `android:timePickerMode="spinner"` but I don't think I can pass an XML attribute through react-native can I?

I also found a suggestion in comments to pass [defStyleAttr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926727/android-api-21-timepicker-widget) to do this, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, see the list of [Argument Types](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#argument-types) from the React Native document for Android Native Modules.

> **Argument Types**
>
> The following argument types are supported for methods
>   annotated with @ReactMethod and they directly map to their JavaScript
>   equivalents
>
> - Boolean -> Bool
> - Integer -> Number
> - Double -> Number
> - Float -> Number
> - String -> String
> - Callback -> function
> - ReadableMap -> Object
> - ReadableArray -> Array

So, you can pass the extra field for `timePickerMode` as a String by updating the `options` that the JS side passes to include it.

```
var options = {
    ...this.props,
    hour:date.getHours(),
    minute:date.getMinutes(),
    timePickerMode:"spinner"
};
```

And then get that value from the ReadableMap in your custom `TimePicker` constructor.

```
String timePickerMode = options.hasKey("timePickerMode") ?
        options.getString("timePickerMode") : defaultTimePickerMode;
```

Now you have the value you wish to set. Unfortunately it does not appear that `timePickerMode` can be set programmatically. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27277338/4348328) asks how to do it and @alanv (whose profile indicates they are a Software Engineer at Google) indicates that it is not possible at runtime.