# Android API 21+ - hide analog clock in TimePickerDialog programmatically

Tags: android, android-timepicker, timepickerdialog

Since Android 5.0, [`TimePickerDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) displays an analog clock by default. How can I hide the analog clock(change display mode) by code?

To obtain similar result of TimePicker in xml:

```
...android:timePickerMode="spinner">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `defStyleAttr` or `defStyleRes` in when you create your time picker.

**According to:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/26961308/4409113 second comment from ***alanv***

Check the following links also:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TimePicker_timePickerMode

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#timePickerMode

Hope that helps.