# Picker showing as clock instead of spinner

Tags: android, timepicker, picker

I was creating a one of my activities separately from my main project because it was a big thing.

After making it work, I merged everything in my main app. Most of it was copy-paste and just change the paths and such.

Now, my problem is my time picker has a completely different look.

It should look like this [picker how it should be][1]

but it looks like this [how it's looking right now][2]

Like I said, I didn't change anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

---

Comment: the timePicker will change in different android

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Give us your code and also layout res

Comment: I don't have a res, I did it on the .kt file. Check my EDIT in 10 seconds and it'll be on my post

Comment: added, you can check now

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449723/is-it-possible-to-change-the-style-of-an-android-l-timepickerdialog

Comment: I saw it, but I don't know how to use that constructor since mine is set up differently. Could you give me a help with it?

Comment: Hello @YosiPramajaya, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: No. The only way is to declare it through Xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TimePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner">
</TimePicker>
```

Set timePickerMode to be Spinner

Comment: Raj, if you saw what I wrote I don't have a res, I did it on my kt file. Thanks anyways