# TimePickerDialog in spinner mode

Tags: android, android-timepicker

In my project, I use `TimepickerDialog` to show the time in a `TextView`. My `Timepickerdialog` is shown as a clock, but I want it shown as a spinner. How can I do this?

Comment: [timepicker with spinner mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#attr_android:timePickerMode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the style of an Android L TimePickerDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449723/is-it-possible-to-change-the-style-of-an-android-l-timepickerdialog)

Answer (score 1):

use this code show time picker as spinner

```
    public void showCustomTimePicker()
    {

          final Calendar myCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
          int hour = myCalender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
          int minute = myCalender.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener myTimeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    if (view.isShown()) {
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                        myCalender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                    }
                }
            };
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar, myTimeListener, hour, minute, true);
            timePickerDialog.setTitle("Choose hour:");
            timePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            timePickerDialog.show();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
  TimePickerDialog picker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker tp, int sHour, int sMinute) {
                    //eText.setText(sHour + ":" + sMinute);
                }
            }, 2, 3, false);
    picker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
           picker .show();
```

Comment: `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar` is deprecated in API 28.

Comment: I love you . . .

Comment: @JonForhan Hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

I used the below code to get the Timepicker in spinner mode.

```
private fun showTimePicker() {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        // date picker dialog
        val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
            mSelectedTime = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(c.time)
            root.tvTime.text = mSelectedTime
        }
        val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(requireContext(),AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, timeSetListener, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(requireContext()))
        timePickerDialog.show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to specify a theme and add the next style property

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="TimePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:timePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[here](https://medium.com/@yottafactory/android-timepicker-timepicker-dialog-spinner-clock-mode-b92ad4c4cb5c) are some related info

Answer (score -2):

Add `android:timePickerMode = "1"` for spinner mode

and

`android:timePickerMode="2"` for clock mode.

**Edit**

Use a theme in constructor of TimePickerDialog like this

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(DateTimePickerDialogActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog, onTimeSetListener, hour, minute, is24Hour);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a timePickerDialog, not a timePicker

Comment: @zahras: Use a theme that used spinner such as `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog`

Comment: `android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog` is deprecated in API 28.

Comment: Is there a non-deprecated theme that uses the spinner?

Answer (score -3):

```
TimePickerDialog nTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, 2,
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker pTimePicker, int hr, int min) {
                TextView.setText(MessageFormat.format("{0}:{1}", hr, min));
            }
        },
        mHour, mMin, false);
nTimePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Intervals");
nTimePickerDialog.show();
```